# NotificationExtenderService not able to resolve after updating Onesignal dependencies from 3.0 to 4.0

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, onesignal

Good day,
I developed an app that can receive notifications from Onesignal. As per the latest target requirement of Google Play, as dependencies are updated only issue is with OneSignal. I updated from `implementation ('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.1')` to latest version     `implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[4.0.0, 4.99.99]'`.

After this following import files showing error,

```
 import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
 import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;
```

Here is my full code, please help me resolving this issue.

**MyNotificationExtender.java**

```
package ak.wp.meto.notification;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.onesignal.NotificationExtenderService;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedResult;

import ak.wp.meto.R;
import ak.wp.meto.data.sqlite.NotificationDbController;

public class MyNotificationExtenderService extends NotificationExtenderService {

    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
       // OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
        /*
     overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
            @Override
            public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
                // Sets the background notification color to Red on Android 5.0+ devices.
                return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FFFF0000", 16).intValue());
            }
        };
     */
        // OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
        //   Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);
        // Return true to stop the notification from displaying
      //  String postId = receivedResult.payload.notificationID;
        String title = receivedResult.payload.title;
        String messageBody  = receivedResult.payload.body;
        String contentUrl = receivedResult.payload.launchURL;
        String imageUrl = receivedResult.payload.bigPicture;
        //String additionalData = receivedResult.payload.additionalData;

        // insert data into database
        NotificationDbController notificationDbController = new NotificationDbController(MyNotificationExtenderService.this);
        notificationDbController.insertData(title, messageBody, contentUrl, imageUrl);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000})
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        return false;
    }
}
```